# How to Update Html in clob column

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I cannot update html content in clob column:

```
DECLARE
   LONGLITERAL RAW(32767) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(
        '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Promotional email template</title>
          </head>
            <body bgcolor="#eeeeee">
              <!-- Start Header -->
             </body>
          </html>');
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  UPDATE table_name SET gno_clob = :1 WHERE id = 'column_id' USING LONGLITERAL;
END;
```

I have also tried

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  UPDATE table_name SET gno_clob = LONGLITERAL WHERE id = 'column_id';
END;
```

Errors

```
    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" 
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error
```

- any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: `execute immediate` needs a string with dynamic sql. You don't have dynamic SQL. Just remove `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: thanks a_horse for valuable solution

Comment: Why do you use RAW datatype? Unless you run a (very) old Oracle database version, you should switch to CLOB. RAW is here just for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
SQL> create table a(tid number ,tc clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into a values(1,null);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> DECLARE
            LONGLITERAL RAW(32767) := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <title>Promotional email template</title>
            </head>
                <body bgcolor="#eeeeee">
                    <!-- Start Header -->
                 </body>
            </html>');
BEGIN
UPDATE a SET tc = LONGLITERAL WHERE tid=1;
END;
/  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14  

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but still error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following:

   
   <an alternat
ORA-06550: line 175, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" The symbol "END" was ignored.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action: